# PMF of two randomly chosen biased coins

Tags: probability

I have two coins, one of which is biased P(heads) = p and one of which is fair.
I pick one of the coins at random and use it for the rest of the game.
I flip the coin 100 times and want to find the PMF for number of heads

I know how to get the PMF of a biased coin where x = # heads
$$ P(X=x) = {100 \choose x} p^x(1-p)^{10-x} $$
and of the fair coin
$$ P(X=x) = {100 \choose x} .5^{10} $$

My problem comes with putting them together.

There's a 50/50 chance I get either coin so I want to just multiply each PMF by $\frac{1}{2}$  and add them but this seems too simple.

I haven't been able to find examples of this sort of problem anywhere so I'm not sure I'm not the right track.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you pick the coin at random for every toss, or do you pick it once and for all?

Comment: You pick it once and then use that coin for the ten tosses

Comment: The *hundred* tosses, I reckon? :)

Comment: haha yes, 100, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, conditioned on picking the fair coin, a pmf denoted by $p_f$ that you know how to compute.

You have, conditioned on picking the bias coin, a pmf denoted by $p_b$ that you know how to compute.

So the pmf overall is $p^\ast$ given by 
$$\begin{align}
p^\ast(n) &= \Pr[X=n\mid \text{fair}]\cdot\Pr[\text{fair}]+\Pr[X=n\mid \text{biased}]\cdot\Pr[\text{biased}] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\Pr[X=n\mid \text{fair}]+\Pr[X=n\mid \text{biased}]\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(p_f(n) + p_b(n)\right)
\end{align}$$
as you suggested.

---

**Edit:** this follows from the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). If $A_1,\dots, A_m$ are events that partition the space of outcomes, then for any event $E$,
$$
\Pr[E] = \sum_{k=1}^m \Pr[E\cap A_k] = \sum_{k=1}^m \Pr[E\mid A_k]\cdot\Pr[A_k].
$$

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how to work with conditional and absolute probabilities? Suppose you want to look at the probability that an rv X takes a particular value, but you know that it depends on some other (possibly unobserved) random effect Y. Then you can say that:

$Pr(X = x) = \sum_y Pr(X = x | Y = y) \times Pr(Y = y)$

i.e. you take the probability of X taking that value conditional on a given value of Y, then take the weighted sum of all those probabilities. In your case, your event Y is the choice of coin, so you definitely can just take half of each of the conditional distributions, since you've got a 50% chance of selecting one or the other. Then all you have to do is see whether you can simplify the expression at all.

Comment: Interesting, I've seen conditional probablilty before but I'm not quite clear on how this is accounting for both X being biased and X being fair. In this case would you find Pr(X=x|Y = biased) and add it to  Pr(X=x|Y = fair)?

Comment: @Indigo Yes.  It's the **Law of Total Probability**. It is that simple.$$\mathsf P(X{=}x) ~=~ \mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}F)~\mathsf P(Y{=}F)+\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}B)~\mathsf P(Y{=}B) \\ = \tfrac 1 2\left(\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}F)+\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}B)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

It is actually correct. In fact if you call $C_1$ the case in which you are tossing the biased coin and $C_2$ the other you have:
$$P(p=x)=P(p=x|C_1)P(C_1)+P(p=x|C_2)P(C_2) $$ and that is equal to doing the mean between the two values you found, as you did, because $P(C_1)=P(C_2)=1/2$

Comment: You are missing the factors $\mathbb{P}(C_1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(C_2)$.

Comment: edited, forgot to write them